# Image memory usage

Tags: image, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, flex4.5

I have an image with 26,4KB. It is loaded by the class Frame bellow. Why does the Profiling Tool from Flex shows a usage of 1388KB for this instance of Frame.

```
public class Frame extends Group
    {
        public function Frame(source:Object)// image with 26,4K
        {           
            var image:BitmapImage;
            image = new BitmapImage();
            image.smooth = true;
            image.source = source;
            this.addElement(image);         
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BitmapImages are essentially an **uncompressed** rectangular array containing the bytes determining pixel colors.

I imagine your input file is a `JPG/JPEG`, `PNG`, `GIF`? (basically, it's compressed).

Imagine an image `100px by 100px, 32bit RGBA colors` (Red/Green/Blue/Alpha).

The memory requirements for this **BitmapImage** would be in the neighborhood of `100 * 100 * (32 / 8)` (X * Y * bytesPerPixel) = 40K bytes.  But that *SAME* image as a `JPG` might compress down to 3K or something. (or `GIF`, or `PNG`, etc.)

It has to be stored as a bitmap at some point so that it can be copied (blitted) to video memory for display.  Perhaps `flex` has alternative image storage types you could use/try?

Comment: My picture has 1024x534. Horizontal and vertical resolution of 96dpi and 24 Dit depth. What about the s:image is it better to display the image?

Comment: {Grin} Haven't the foggiest!  Try it!  In my experience, it's really not that much of a concern unless you're tinkering with memory starved embedded devices.  Play with things, try ideas, with a good SCM (git!) you can easily roll back if something doesn't work as well as you wanted.